# How to open the stdout with Notepad++?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, pipe, stdout

On OSX TextMate have the alias `mate` which you can use with the pipe to open other program's stdout.

How can I achieve the same effect in Windows 7 with Notepad++?

Ex.: `git diff master|edit`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No**, Windows does not have equivalent functionality to `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd` on Unixes. (It would be *stdin*, not stdout, from Notepad++'s point of view.) While GUI programs *can* read from stdin, they must be specially written to do so.

---

```
@echo off & setlocal
set f=%temp%\stdin-%random%%random%%random%.txt
more > "%f%"
start /wait notepad++ "%f%"
del "%f%"
```

If you don't want the batch file to "/wait" for notepadd++ to exit, you can replace the above "start /wait" line with these two lines:

---

```
start notepad++ "%f%"
REM Windows timeout won't work inside batch files. Use ping hack instead.
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 3 -w 10000 > nul
```

Comment: And there's no way to write a wrapper?

Comment: @Lohoris: See update.