# How can I pipe console output directly to Notepad?

Tags: windows, command-line, notepad

I'm running an application on the command prompt or a [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) shell, and I would like to get the output into Notepad, for easier review and editing later on.

I tried the following, but I always get an empty instance of Notepad:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | notepad
```

I'm aware that I can redirect the output to another file and then open the file in Notepad. I'd like to avoid the extra step, because I'm just used to piping into [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) or less on non-Windows systems.

Comment: Of course, you can pipe to `more` on Windows too.

Comment: Why not pipe to file and simply shell execute the new file path - let the OS handle the presentation application. Does it _have_ to be notepad?

Comment: @Gusdor The question is primarily about avoiding to create a (temporary) file.

Comment: Notepad's functionality is so limited that you can barely do anything with it. Since you are familiar with `vim`, why not just install it?

Comment: @C.R. I could do that on my own computers, but I regularly work on computers which I don't own. So it's helpful to know which options there are without installing third-party software.

Comment: Again, portable apps in a usb pen are here to help you. Or just create a temporary file and do a `type c:\windows\explorer.exe > temp-file && del temp-file` to overwrite it and remove it in the end

Comment: Not to be confused with [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B)... (the search engines don't know the difference).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From what I can tell, there is no way to directly pipe into Notepad.

However, you can pipe into `clip` and then *paste* in notepad, like so:

```
 diff file1.txt file2.txt | clip && notepad
```

Then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Notepad.

Comment: Would it work if you'd redirect the output to file3.txt, and then `&& notepad file3.txt`?

Comment: @Konerak Yes, that would work and that is exactly what I was trying to avoid (as explained in the question) ;)

Answer (score 33):

Consider using [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc), or in your case gVim if you prefer a graphical environment.

You can then pipe into it with a single hyphen as an argument, which instructs Vim/gVim to read from standard input.

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | gvim -
```

Comment: install it, Notepad is really limited you can't use it for this. you can even have it in portable apps: http://portableapps.com/apps/development/gvim_portable

Comment: Can also do this from within vim: `:%!diff file1.txt file2.txt`

Comment: @TankorSmash So do I, but that's not the point of the question ;) For further pro and con discussions regarding vim (or any other topic), please find me on [chat], comment threads are not a great way to have a conversation :(

Comment: @OliverSalzburg I was trying to suggest that gvim is available on Windows, since I understood your comment to mean that it wasn't. I was wrong.

Comment: `-` is often used to mean "read from stdin", so this isn't strictly limited to `vim`. Other editors use `-i` (e.g. `kate`).

Answer (score 9):

[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/09/08/10555736.aspx)'s a short Windows program that does it *properly* (without clobbering the clipboard). It should be adaptable to PowerShell, and I might update this answer if I get the time, but you can also just use that program directly.

Well, how about PowerShell? No need to install another application. Unfortunately, you *will* need to create a script file somewhere in your `PATH`...

### Short version you can use

If you create a batch file (e.g. `ShowInNotepad.bat`) with the following contents and place it in your `PATH` somewhere:

```
@echo off
clip
powershell -Command $process = Start-Process -PassThru notepad;$SW_SHOW = 5;$sig = '[DllImport("""user32.dll""")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);';Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32;[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindow($process.Id, $SW_SHOW) ^| Out-Null;Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^^V');
```

you can then just call `echo blah | ShowInNotepad` from anywhere!

Note that this *does* assume that you're using a recent-ish version of Windows (Vista+) and have not disabled PowerShell or uninstalled the .NET framework. In other words, a default Windows installation will work.

---

### Lengthy explanation and alternatives

The easiest way I can think of is to automate the paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) action. Which at least one other answer is already doing, but that one uses AHK - you might have better luck getting PowerShell to work in a locked-down corporate environment.

Let's get on with the script, yea?

```
#start notepad, get process object (to get pid later)
$process = Start-Process -PassThru notepad;

# activate Notepad window
# based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/4994020/1030702
# SW_SHOW activates and shows a window http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
$SW_SHOW = 5;
$sig = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);';
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32;
[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindow($process.Id, $SW_SHOW) | Out-Null;

# send a "Ctrl+V" keystroke to the active window
# from http://stackoverflow.com/a/17851491/1030702
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^V');
```

It's pretty straightforward, so I won't bother explaining the script more than the comments already do.

#### Usage

To use it, you just need to place the script in a `.ps1` file (e.g. `ShowInNotepad.ps1`), place it somewhere in your `PATH` and then call `powershell ShowInNotepad.ps1` after placing the text you want to display in the clipboard.

Example:

```
echo blah | clip && powershell ShowInNotepad.ps1
```

Unfortunately, executing PowerShell scripts can sometimes be difficult (execution policies and all). Therefore, I've condensed this script to a one-liner you can call directly from the Command Prompt, or even place into a batch file:

```
powershell -Command $process = Start-Process -PassThru notepad;$SW_SHOW = 5;$sig = '[DllImport("""user32.dll""")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);';Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32;[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindow($process.Id, $SW_SHOW) ^| Out-Null;Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^^V');
```

If you create a batch file (e.g. `ShowInNotepad.bat`) with the following contents and place it in your `PATH` somewhere:

```
@echo off
clip
powershell -Command $process = Start-Process -PassThru notepad;$SW_SHOW = 5;$sig = '[DllImport("""user32.dll""")] public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);';Add-Type -MemberDefinition $sig -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32;[Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindow($process.Id, $SW_SHOW) ^| Out-Null;Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms;[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('^^V');
```

you can then just call `echo blah | ShowInNotepad` from anywhere!

Comment: Honestly if you're going to write a PS script I would just create a file with a Guid name in the temp file folder and delete it when I was done.  Automating the paste seems too brittle (like what if you lose focus at the wrong time or something)?

Comment: @emodendroket Unfortunately, when you're trying to force stream input into a program that doesn't natively support it, nothing is truly clean. Creating a temp file has its own (minor) drawbacks: you don't actually get a "new file", so the `Save` and exit on modified behaviours are different. Short of replacing Notepad itself or directly injecting the text into its edit control, there's not many other options. Of course, this method has the drawback of clobbering clipboard contents (though those are supposed to be ephemeral anyway). I don't think losing focus is a major issue; it's an...

Comment: ...extremely unlikely race condition (between the `ShowWindow` and sending keystrokes). And this method does require a bit more setup (creating the script file) to use, yes.

Answer (score 5):

How about using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)?

Save the following as `stdin.ahk` and put it in your AutoHotkey directory:

```
StdIn(max_chars=0xfff)
{
    static hStdIn=-1
    ; The following is for vanilla compatibility
    ptrtype := (A_PtrSize = 8) ? "ptr" : "uint"

    if (hStdIn = -1)
    {
        hStdIn := DllCall("GetStdHandle", "UInt", -10,  ptrtype) ; -10=STD_INPUT_HANDLE
        if ErrorLevel
            return 0
    }

    max_chars := VarSetCapacity(text, max_chars*(!!A_IsUnicode+1), 0)

    ret := DllCall("ReadFile"
        ,  ptrtype, hStdIn        ; hFile
        ,  "Str", text          ; lpBuffer
        , "UInt", max_chars*(!!A_IsUnicode+1)     ; nNumberOfBytesToRead
        , "UInt*", bytesRead    ; lpNumberOfBytesRead
        ,  ptrtype, 0)            ; lpOverlapped

    return text
}

loop 
{
    sleep 100 ;wait for data
    Buffer:=StdIn()
    PipeText:=PipeText . Buffer
    IfWinActive Untitled - Notepad
        {
        SendInput {Raw}%PipeText%
        PipeText = 
        }
}
```

Then the command line:

```
ping -t www.google.com | AutoHotkeyA32.exe stdin.ahk
```

Pipes the output of the command into Notepad, so long as the window is open and titled `Untitled - Notepad`.  In the event that the window is not active then it will cheerfully buffer in the background until the window is active.  You can even go away to another program and it will carry on buffering once more.

This seems to die when the program outputting to our standard input dies though...

(For information, the stdin() code was shamelessly half-inched from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/54559-stdin/))

Comment: ...wow. If you're going to go to that extent, might as well write a whole compiled program! Probably be more efficient too :P Upvote for the effort though.

Comment: Downvote from me im afraid. Overengineering in the classical sense. Who is version controlling this script? Does autohotkey need a license for commercial applications? Who monitors that?

Comment: @Gusdor The entire Internet is full of non-version controlled code snippets. We have the benefit of even having [a revision history](http://superuser.com/posts/772453/revisions) for this post. I also don't see how commercial licensing has anything to do with this question? AHK is used by *a lot* of people, and they might find this answer useful.

Comment: @slhck I was simply remarking on the pitfalls of this solution, not its validity.

Comment: @slhck: Content on this site is covered by Creative Commons.

Answer (score 4):

This is totally possible; I just tried it.  I'm assuming Notepad is set to open txt files by default:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt > output.txt && start output.txt && timeout /T 3 && del output.txt
```

OK, you're technically creating a file, but it doesn't get saved.

Piping into more is also an option.

Comment: Be careful - if you already have an `output.txt` this will clobber it. Marginally safer would be to use `%temp%/somerandomstring.txt`.

Comment: It's more safe to save an output file in temp directory - take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/a/424215/92334) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an ugly, but effective way to accomplish this:

```
$OutputString = 'Hello World'
$WScript = New-Object -ComObject 'wscript.shell'
$WScript.Run('notepad.exe') | Out-Null
do 
    {
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }
until ($WScript.AppActivate('notepad'))
$WScript.SendKeys($OutputString)
```

Just be sure to only send text output.  Other data will potentially be interpreted as control characters (CTRL, ALT, DEL, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Yet another solution to consider!  VS Code can receive piped input also, if you now use this instead of Notepad.  I noticed this in V1.41, don't know when it was implemented.

In this example:

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | code -
```

Note the dash as a parameter to Code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of VBScript based solutions that may work (although .. they rely a little on apps opening on time):

pipe2key.vbs - opens the application specified as the first argument, and then sends StdIn as keystrokes to it. Needs to be used with cscript.exe as wscript does not provide StdIn access. Probably quite slow for long documents - but won't clobber the clipboard

```
Set inPipe=wScript.StdIn
Set wShell=wScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wShell.Run wScript.Arguments(0), 5 ' Execute specified app, foreground it's window
wScript.Sleep 500 ' Wait for app to load
KeysToEscape="{}[]()^+%"
KeysToDrop=vbLf
While Not inPipe.AtEndOfStream
    keyChar=inPipe.Read(1)
    If InStr(KeysToDrop, keyChar) = 0 Then
        If InStr(KeysToEscape, keyChar) > 0 Then
            wShell.SendKeys "{" & keyChar & "}"
        Else
            wShell.SendKeys keyChar
        End If
    End If
Wend
```

Example usage: `diff file1.txt file2.txt | cscript pipe2key.vbs notepad.exe`

Or, pasteinto.vbs. Automates the CTRL-V operation after launching an app (thus uses the 'clip' command as mentioned in previous answers). Considerably faster and cleaner (in my opinion) than pipe2key.vbs, but the process will overwrite the clipboard

```
Set wShell=wScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wShell.Run wScript.Arguments(0), 5 ' Execute specified app, foreground it's window
wScript.Sleep 500 ' Wait for app to load
wShell.SendKeys "^v"
```

Example usage: `diff file1.txt file2.txt | clip && pasteinto notepad.exe`

Answer (score -1):

Something like this "might" work.

Aw, ya didn't realize this is something you'd be doing manually each time (from the sounds of it).  You might be able to make some sort of macro or something to do it for you each time to speed up the process.  Not sure on that one.

`diff file1.txt file2.txt > file.txt | sleep 1 | notepad.exe file.txt | rm file.txt`

It would have to finish writing the diff contents to file.txt in order for it to load the entirety of the diff operation which I'm not sure if it'll do.  There might be a way to pause somehow between the pipe operation if that is the case.

Comment: The goal is to *not* create a temporary file and I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with your syntax there ;)

Comment: "for easier review and editing later on" I figured that's what you wanted?  And as Rev1.0 pointed out and amended to, it works.  This is for dos however, I'm not sure if cygwin would have the same results.

Comment: I lied, what he did, doesn't work in dos but it does work in cygwin (if that's a good enough solution).  You can delete the temp file after you're done with it in notepad by simply adding another pipe.

`diff file1.txt file2.txt > file.txt | sleep 1 | notepad.exe file.txt | rm file.txt`

Comment: Why is his use of `|` disturbing if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I guess because an & would be adequate since actually nothing needs to be "piped" between those calls.

Comment: @Rev1.0 Correct. `&`, `&&` and `||` are operators to chain commands together. All 3 behave differently in how they proceed if a command generates a non-0 return value. `|` is completely different as it is used to *pipe* output from one program to another. The result might be what you wanted, but using one of the chaining operators makes the intent clearer, because no actual piping is desired in that example. For additional reference: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx

Comment: @Codezilla I think the idea in my post is pretty similar to yours but it's valid command prompt syntax.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: `&` is not really comparable to `&&` and `||`. `cmd1 && cmd2` and `cmd1 || cmd2` both run `cmd1`, wait for it to finish, and then, conditionally, run `cmd2`, depending on the return value from `cmd1`. `cmd1 & cmd2` starts `cmd1` in the background, and then *immediately, unconditionally* runs `cmd2` concurrently.

Comment: @Scott It does not seem to be the case. The commands run in sequence (at least in Windows 7). Try `timeout /t 5 & echo test`. `test` only be displayed after `timeout` finished counting.

Comment: @cychoi: You're right. I was looking at `diff`, `sleep`, and `rm`, and I lost track of the fact that they were talking about the Windows command prompt, and not a Unix shell. In Windows, `cmd1 & cmd2` means sequential execution; same as `cmd1; cmd2` in Unix.

Answer (score -3):

You can't, Notepad is too limited for this! Better yet... install [Cygwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin) and workaround all this "lack of features" of Windows. You can then use the command you already know.

AFAIK, very few Windows program support pipelining, even worse for GUI programs.

You can try to open feature requests to one of the "windows tail" programs to add that.

Comment: I already use cygwin. This is really a problem specific to interaction with Notepad.

Comment: Good Raymond Chen piece:  [In particular, if the solution begins with 'First, install...' you've pretty much lost out of the gate.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/22/558007.aspx)

Comment: @emodendroket some times people use the wrong tool for a job... and for almost any case, notepad is the wrong tool, is so simple and limited :)

Comment: @higuita I'm a devoted Emacs user but sometimes Notepad is the better tool for what I want to do.

Answer (score -3):

My language is not English so sorry for mistakes.

I think u can't directly put the output into the open Notepad. May be I am wrong about it. You have to create a file with the output in it in order to work on it. The command tee can pipe the output to two or may be more commands or files in the same time.

man tee

Don't forget to use >> instead > when you redurect the output into the file. The > will overwrite the file, >> will add the output after whatever has already in that file.

Comment: `tee` is usually not available on Windows and even if it was, it wouldn't help with this problem.