# Command output to notepad

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Trying to get command output to Notepad. I need way to get command output and place in newly opened Notepad window. How to achieve that?

I do `dir>>notepad` but get nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pipe console output directly to Notepad?](https://superuser.com/questions/772269/how-can-i-pipe-console-output-directly-to-notepad)

Comment: many dupes of this question, note that an alternative way to get a file listing is to use windows explorer, highlight the files you are interested in, SHIFT+rightClick, select "copy as path" and then paste it into notepad. This will include the entire path.

Comment: `dir > temp.txt && notepad temp.txt`